# Silverlight unable to load large number of controls

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight control that outright quits rendering controls after a large number of nested child controls have been rendered. The main control is databound to an object similar in structure to the following:

```
MainViewModel 
  -> MatrixViewModel
      -> List<SectionViewModel>
            -> List<BuildingBlockViewModel>
```

The `MainViewModel` has a child object property called `MatrixViewModel`, which in turn has a list of `SectionViewModel`s, and each `SectionViewModel` has a list of `BuildingBlockViewModel`s.

Each view model has a corresponding xaml view that contains a number of buttons, checkboxes, etc. And the SectionViewModel and BuildingBlockViewModel collections are rendered using standard ItemsControls within the xaml of their parent views.

I've found that if I remove a few of the xaml controls (buttons, stackpanels, etc) from the lowest level building block view then the control is able to render them all. However, as soon as I add the removed xaml back in it again ceases to load all of the controls.

It's as though Silverlight is bumping up against some sort of maximum object tree size or something. I've monitored memory and there is ample CPU memory left when the application loads so I'm not even close to pegging out the CPU.

Comment: Is Virtualization not an option?

Comment: Good question, virtualization could potentially fix this issue but that doesn't address the root of why this behavior is occurring.

Comment: Well, the more you load into memory at once, the more likely you are to run into performance issues. With SL, it just seems to choke and not display. For the techicals, you'll find many a blog and article entry regarding it.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this is because of an upper limit of objects in the visual tree. I've seen Silverlight render millions of elements without choking - and in cases where it did choke, it wouldn't just drop visuals. I would bet that your problem isn't due to performance issues but something else - although it's not possible to tell without further information.